# How to display a Flatlist component on app's main screen?

Tags: react-native

I'm getting started with React Native, and followed the basics from React Native tutorial, being able to create and modify Flatlist as I wish. I'm now trying to create a simple to-do application, that would call different classes to home screen. The issue I have is that while I can call simple text from different classes, I'm unable to display the contents from a list.

Here is the code in Homescreen.js:

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar";
import MainComponent from "../components/MainComponent"

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <NavBar/>
            <MainComponent/>

        </View>
    );
};
```

And here is the code in MainComponent.js:

```
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class MainComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text> This text is shown when running the application </Text>
                <FlatList
                    data={[
                        {key: 'Placeholder data 1'},
                        {key: 'Placeholder data 2'},
                    ]}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
                />
            </View>

        );}}
```

When calling the "MainComponent/", it displays "This text is shown when running the application" -text, but the contents of the Flatlist are not shown on the screen. If I copy the MainComponent.js shown above to a separate project and run it alone, it displays all the contents of the Flatlist correctly. But my current solution is not working.

Comment: Could you post your styles please?

Comment: @tuomas make sure that styles.container has flex:1

Comment: Styles look like this:
```const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 22
    },
    item: {
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        height: 44,
    },
})
```

Straight from the React Native tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason that made the list to not be displayed. It was the flex

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ container: { flex: 1, paddingTop: 22 }, item: { padding: 10, fontSize: 18, height: 44, }, })
```

Taking the "flex: 1" out of the code fixed the issue :)